# Grab complex data from mysql and show them using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on my PHP script for a while now but I am currently stuck in complex data grab and show as a table.

I have a MySQL table structured like this:

```
ID (AI) / UID / DYNA / CNT / QID
1       / 8   / car / 0    / 9
2       / 2   / bal / 1    / 9
3       / 0   / car / 0    / 8 
4       / 3   / lov / 1    / 2
5       / 6   / bal / 1    / 9 
6       / 9   / cal / 0    / 9
7       / 11  / los / 1    / 9
```

And I want to grab this data and structure it like this (The data is selected by qid):

```
DYNA / CAR / BAL / LOS
CNT /   0  / 2   / 1
```

The CNT table is the total of CNT in the database for example "car" in the database have two records their cnt is  0 and 0 so 0 + 0 = 0 
So I think the query might be:

```
Select * from TABLE where qid = 9 ....
```

Comment: looks like you need: `sum(cnt)` and  `group by dyna`

Comment: Can you please write the full request as long as i am planning to echo these results in a table using php. thank you in advance

Comment: This is a pretty low-effort question. You're not even showing us what you've tried. The question seems to be cut-off as well.
The data structure you're wanting to get is also maybe a bit poor in design. It'd be much easier on your database if you aggregated the data using a "GROUP BY" clause and dealt with the data row-by-row instead of columns like you have.

Comment: @Izodn it's is not possible to use group by as long as every record have it's own uid.

Comment: @Yassine It is certainly possible. You only must group by what you select. So if you're only selecting cnt and dyna, you can group by DYNA and SUM(cnt).

Comment: But you want to get the final (result) table just with SQL? Or do you want to: 1st) get the MySQL results; 2) structure results using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select DYNA, sum(CNT) as CNT from table where QID = 9 group by DYNA;
```

It should give you an output like

```
DYNA | CNT
----------
CAR  | 0
BAL  | 2
LOS  | 1
```

**UPDATE**

If you also want to know the number of records in each group add a count in your query which is:

```
select DYNA, count(*) as num, sum(CNT) as CNT from table where QID = 9 group by DYNA;
```

Comment: Your code works like a charm (y) but I want just to ask if there is an option for another tweak add  a row which count how many records of DYNA for example there is two record with car in the table. thanks in advance.

Comment: While this is a great answer, it doesn't provide the data structure @Yassine is asking for. My suggestion to Yassine is to use this query, and modify your logic to handle it by rows instead of by columns.

Comment: @Yassine please check my update hope that answered your question.

Comment: @Izodn his answer is exactly what i was looking for, thank you ! And a big thanks to USER3360140